# Phonegap iPhone plugin SoundPlug, cant get it working

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, phonegap-plugins

I dragged the h and m files into Xcode under Plugins dir. Then the "Choose options for adding files" window pops up and I select Destination: ticked, and Folders: Create folders for ref for any added folders.

The i run it and try to use the plugin and get this error:

ERROR: Plugin 'SoundPlug' not found, or is not a PGPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in PhoneGap.plist.

Im running Xcode 4.2 and trying to tes on iOS5 similator.

The same problem with PGLowLatancy plugin!

Comment: I could get it working at last. I realise that you have to add the entry to the PhoneGap.plist file insite the PLUGINS options. why dont they just say that!! any ways, not it "plays" but makes no sound. well i dont think it actually plays

Comment: What did you end up putting in Cordova.plist to get it working?